# Unauthorize account - Google Device Access - Nest

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nest-device-access

I'm unable to figure out from the docs how to unauthorize a user's linked account and stop receiving events from their linked devices. Is there a request for this? Or maybe by invalidating the user's Oauth2 access/refresh token?

Comment: Please provide more details, background, etc. Which documentation are you using? You want to authentication linkedin account on the Nest or it's your application?

Comment: Hi, I'm working on integrating the control of a user's Nest devices using Google's Device Access platform (https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access). Users sync by a typical Oauth2 Flow. Once they are synced, I am able to listen to their Nest's changes. My question is about how to unlink a user. For example, a user wants to unlink his account through my application. On that event, I would like to notify to Device Access to stop sending me events for that user, and invalidate their Oauth2 tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token can be revoked either by the user via https://myaccount.google.com/permissions or by revoking the token by passing it to https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke

See https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest_8